# Add GIF image to marker of Google Map Api v2

Tags: android, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2

When I add GIF Image to marker of google map V2 the image is shown but it stops its movement.
Why? And how can I solve this issue and make the image do its movement?

Hope anyone can help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Marker Icon in google maps android api v2 is a static image and you cannot change the icon once you have created the marker. So if you are trying to include any animation using GIF images, it will not be supported and only a single image from the GIF will be shown as the icon.

An option to achieve changing marker image is to programatically `remove()` the marker after a certain time and then immediately add the marker using `addMarker` with a different image set as icon in `MarkerOptions()` and retaining other properties.