# how to set gif animated image in place of default marker position on map in android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

As I've searched about it and came to know that it can be possible to place numbers of image (Makers) of different types at the same position on `Map`, which act as the gif image.

```
Marker currentMarker = null;
    for(int i =0;i<=100000;i++)
    {
        currentMarker.remove();
        if(i%2==0)                
        {
            currentMarker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(new LatLng(latitude,longitude))
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.RIGHT)));
        }
        else {
            currentMarker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(new LatLng(latitude,longitude))
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.LEFT)));
        }
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
    }
```

using above code I can manage the images by odd even.

***My question*** is that can **we place the GIF *(image) marker on the google ??**.If it is possible than please let me know.

If there is any error in my code **OR** question than please let me know about it thanks :)

Comment: No, you cannot add `gif` to marker, detailed answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18715504/add-gif-image-to-marker-of-google-map-api-v2

Comment: Thanks @W4R10CK ...For yours valuable comment... It means that we can not place the **GIF** on the _google map_.