# Android Google Maps set .gif as marker icon

Tags: android, google-maps, gif

I would like set GIF as marker icon. Is it possible? I haven't found a clear answer to this question.

Comment: Not possible. But a few options, check those links https://stackoverflow.com/a/18733642/1281180,  https://stackoverflow.com/q/32715920/1281180

Comment: Did you find a solution?