# set Gif Image As a marker android

Tags: android, maps, google-maps-markers

Is there any possible to set Gif Image as marker android google map.In my project i want to set gif image as a marker

```
if (bmp != null) {
            System.out.println("----marker-set----------" + base64);
            marker = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(new LatLng(MyCurrent_lat, MyCurrent_long))
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bmp)));
            googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(MyCurrent_lat, MyCurrent_long),
                    17));
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

From documentation :

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/marker

https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Marker

> Icon A bitmap that's displayed for the marker. If the icon is left
>   unset, a default icon is displayed. You can specify an alternative
>   coloring of the default icon using defaultMarker(float).

You cannot use a GIF image for a Marker, because the icon is static. And you cannot change the image during runtime. However, you can change the image with code ( by completely remove marker it on an event trigger, on timer, etc. and adding it again, with different image).

Answer (score -2):

You Cannot set a `Gif` as a map marker.

> Marker Icon in google maps android api v2 is a static image and you cannot change the icon once you have created the marker. So if you are trying to include any animation using GIF images, it will not be supported and only a single image from the GIF will be shown as the icon.

refrence: [Add GIF image to marker of Google Map Api v2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18715504/add-gif-image-to-marker-of-google-map-api-v2)

Instead default map marker could be changed with a custom marker with desired image as follows:

Create a **custom marker layout** with an image holder (`ImageView`)

Initialise the map marker layout

```
 View marker = ((LayoutInflater)getSystemService(getApplicationContext().LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.custom_marker_layout, null);
 ImageView img = marker.findViewById(R.id.img);
```

Set the image in the `imageView` as :

```
if(bmp!=null)
    {
        img.setImageBitmap(bmp);
    }
```

Set it to the map as:

```
Marker customMarker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
        .position(new LatLng(lati, longi))
        .title(title)
        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(createDrawableFromView(this, marker))));
```

where `createDrawableFromView` is a **method** which is defined as:

```
public static Bitmap createDrawableFromView(Context context, View view)
    {
        DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        ((Activity)context).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
        view.setLayoutParams(new WindowManager.LayoutParams(ActionBar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ActionBar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        view.measure(displayMetrics.widthPixels, displayMetrics.heightPixels);
        view.layout(0, 0, displayMetrics.widthPixels, displayMetrics.heightPixels);
        view.buildDrawingCache();
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getMeasuredWidth(), view.getMeasuredHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        view.draw(canvas);

        return bitmap;
    }
```

Hope it works for you.

Comment: I down vote your answer because event if using Bitmap built from custom marker view layout, It is still static image not animation gif. So your answer wastes time of other people